# WebView qml doesn't work correctly on iOS 11

Tags: ios, qt, webview, qml

I've a problem, i need to open url inside app, and I used a WebView, but doesn't work correctly.

imported this:

```
import QtWebView 1.0
```

my code:

```
Rectangle{
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "Orange"
    anchors.fill: parent
    z:9999999

    WebView {
        id: webviewer
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://www.google.com"

        onLoadProgressChanged: {
            console.log(webviewer.loadProgress)
        }
    }
}
```

and in the .pro file i've put:

```
QT += webview
```

And my main.cpp

```
QtWebView::initialize();
```

my console.log is printing correctly the load status, but on the screen I don't see nothing.
Why?

Comment: Just added FYI, tested on Ubuntu, works fine. Qt 5.6.2 64bit.

Comment: I cannot use QT 5.6...there is not solutions on ios 11 with qt 5.9 ?

Comment: Can you change "import QtWebView 1.0"  to 1.1, If that is not working. I am not sure what else. since you are using Qt 5.9 and specific to ios 11, you can post the same in Qt form may give best answer.

Comment: I was alredy work with 1.1 library, maybe on ios11 apple has close the possibility external webview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works on iOS, the solution is:

[image]

Open project in Xcode from build folder, and set App Transport Security Settings, you must add Allow Arbitrary Loads and sets it on YES.
Now the WebView works.

Answer (score 0):

initialize() creates opengl surface, in this case You must first open parent window(surface to display) , other solution is to comment initialize() - page will show. If you'll decide to show it on GL surface, try to se ALWAYSSTACKONTOP attribute to see, if other windows dont cover webview, opengl is rendered first,so any other background can make it not visible. You may also open webview class parented to other, visible window, but if you will show it fullscreen, it will be flicker a while